# Geometry Questions: Triangles

Tags: geometry

Can you guys please help me with these problems?

1. In the triangle shown, $n$ is a positive integer, and $\angle A > \angle B > \angle C$. How many possible values of $n$ are there?

[image]

2. The distance from Capital City to Little Village is 660 miles. From Capital City to Mytown is 310 miles, from Mytown to Yourtown is 200 miles, and from Yourtown to Little Village is 150 miles. How far is it from Mytown to Little Village?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be a better question if you split it into two (since the second is unrelated to what you know), and told us more about what tools you think might be relevant to the problems, or what attempts you've made, or what similar problems you can do. For instance, do you know about the law of sines? How about the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Problem 2, the answer is 350 miles. Using triangle inequality twice, you can get the conclusion that the distance is no smaller than 350 miles and no large than 350 miles. So it can only be 350 miles.

Comment: Thanks, but it would be better to post a solution so everyone can understand...

Answer (score 0):

Both questions are rely on a variation of the triangle inequality.

The Triangle inequality says:
The distance from A to B + distance from B to C is greater than the distance from A to C.  Or, the shortest distance between two points is a straight line.

$d(A,B) + d(B,C) \ge d(A,C)$

It also implies that the sum of the two short sides of a triangle are at least as long as the long side.

And we can rewrite it:
$d(A,B) \ge d(A,C) - d(B,C)$

$4n - 9 \ge n+4 - n-3$

$4n \ge 12\\
n\ge3$

$n = 3$ is stretching the limits, and arguably is not a triangle.  As, all 3 points lie on one line.

If n>3, then we are cool.  And none of the side grow fast enough to break the triangle.  n could be really big, and we would have a satisfactory triangle.

Problem 2: 
d(central city,mytown) + d(mytown,yourtown) + d(yourtown,litte village) = d(central city, little village)

310+200+150 = 660

All 4 cities lie on a line.